# Updated code - How to put all values in a column in Python using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I'm still learning with this technology. May I know how to put all values in one column using python and xlsx writer?

Ex.

```
my_dict = {
'Bob': ['eating', 'watching', 'drinking'], 
'Ann': ['shopping', 'eating', 'drawing'], 
'May': ['riding', 'singing', 'dancing']
}
```

What I did was putting it in another column.

```
col_num = 0
row_num = 7
        
col_num = 0
row_num = 7
        
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    worksheet.write_column(row_num, col_num, key)
    worksheet.write_column(row_num + 1, col_num + 1, value)
    row_num += 1
```

May I know how can I achieve this kind of format?
Hoping to get your opinions and suggestions. Thank you

[image: Table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use write for the key and write_column for value.

Also, increment the row number by the length of value.

```
col_num = 0
row_num = 7
        
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, key)
    worksheet.write_column(row_num,  col_num + 1, value)
    row_num += len(value)

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it now.
This is what I did:

```
row_num = 7
        
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    col_num = 0
    worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, key)
    for i in value:
        col_num = 1
        worksheet.write(row_num, col_num, i)
        row_num += 1
```